# changing the color of the icon along with the color of the link inside a div?

Tags: css

I have a horizontal list with icons and a text link underneath it.

What I am trying to achieve is change the color of the icon link AND the color of the text link as well, when moving the mouse over it. So far, I achieved only to change one of them, not both, even though they are both in the same "a". When the mouse moves over the text link, the text link changes the color but the icon link doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="glyphs character-mapping">
                <li>
                <a href="" class="iconlink">
                  <div data-icon="a" class="icon"></div>Link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="" class="iconlink">
                  <div data-icon="b" class="icon"></div>Link 2</a>
                </li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
.glyphs.character-mapping {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.glyphs.character-mapping li {
margin: 0px 10px 30px;
display: inline-block;
width: 165px;
text-align: center;
}
.glyphs.character-mapping .icon {
margin: 10px 0px 10px 45px;
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
color: #162A36 !important;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 3px;
font-size: 60px; 
}
.glyphs.character-mapping .iconlink:hover{
color: #FF0000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.glyphs.character-mapping .iconlink:hover,
.glyphs.character-mapping .icon:hover {
color: #FF0000 !important;
}
```

HTML specifies that `<a>` elements may only contain inline elements. A `<div>` is a block element, so it may not appear inside an `<a>`.

So why don't you use tag `i` instead of `div` for example

```
<ul class="glyphs character-mapping">
    <li>
        <a href="" class="iconlink">
            <i data-icon="a" class="icon"/>Link 1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" class="iconlink">
            <i data-icon="b" class="icon"/>Link 2
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Strangely, that works when hovering on the icon ...it turns the link red as well, but when hovering only on the link, it doesn't turn the icon red. It only turns the icon red when the mouse is moved on top of it. Maybe a problem with the markup?

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately it still doesn't work. Only the text link changes color when hovering over the text, not the icon :(

Comment: it would be nice if you created fiddle for demonstrate your issue

Comment: Just tried to do it, but for some reason the icons aren't showing up: http://jsfiddle.net/8sv5D/ (Note I had to replace my custom icons set with FontAwesome, so the markup is a tiny bit different but still the same principle).